# Ant task failing because of classpath

Tags: eclipse, ant

My kodoc jdo enhancement tack is failing when I don't have the kodo jar in the **global** entries of the ant configuration.

In my eclipse environment I can build the code with ant just fine. but when I run ant out outside of ant the kodo jar file is not being found.

```
build.xml:106: taskdef class kodo.ant.PCEnhancerTask cannot be found
```

The Task is in the jar file com.bea.core.kodo_1.0.0.0_4-2-0.jar which I have in the classpath. I have printed that out with this trick http://blog.andrewbeacock.com/2005/08/pretty-printing-java-classpaths-using.html.

I have tried reordering the items in the ant `<path id="cp">` but that seems to have no effect.

I am at a loss as to how to make the build file general.

```
<target name="enhance">
    <available property="propfile" file="../../config/pebig.jdo.properties"/>
    <echo>base dir is ${basedir} props is ${propfile}</echo>

    <echo message="|-- compile classpath"/>
    <echo message="|   |"/>
    <echo message="|   |-- ${echo.path.compile}"/>

    <taskdef name="kodoc" classname="kodo.ant.PCEnhancerTask">
        <classpath refid="cp"/>
    </taskdef>

    <kodoc>
        <classpath refid="cp"/>
        <config propertiesFile="${configProperties}"/>
        <fileset dir="${srcdir}">
            <include name="**/*.jdo" />
        </fileset>
    </kodoc>

</target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did this syntax help, or are you already using this?

```
<taskdef resource="propertiesfile name">
    <classpath>
        <fileset file="/path/to/jars"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

please post a code sample.

Comment: The code in the answer needs to be formatted as code to make it easier to read.

Comment: adding classpath to the task def yields java.util.MissingResourceException: C:\Documents and Settings\am4896\workspace\blue ebig\ebig\config\pebig.jdo.properties#null

Comment: The MissingResourceException does nor appear outside of eclipse